# How to find equal names in two *.txt files?

Tags: java

Im new with java (just started a course 2 weeks ago).

Its a college exercise, I have 2 txt files 1.txt and 2.txt, File 1 has 3 names (peter, ann and albert) file 2 (peter, lennon and smeagol).

I have to write a program that read s the files and then compares and answers 3 questions:
   Print the names that are in file 1 and not in file 2. this is done
   Print the names that are in file 2 and not in file 1. this is done
   Print the names that appear in both files.
I just can't find how to compare and give the names that appear in both files.

Here is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        // New BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            "1.txt"));
        // Add all lines from file to ArrayList.
        while (true) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
            break;
            }
            list1.add(line);
        }
        // Close it.
        reader.close();

        // Print size of ArrayList.
        System.out.println("file1: " + list1.size());

        // Print each line.
        for (String line : list1) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }//list1

        System.out.println(" ");

        ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        // New BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            "2.txt"));
        // Add all lines from file to ArrayList.
        while (true) {
            String line = reader1.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
            break;
            }
            list2.add(line);
        }
        // Close it.
        reader1.close();
        // Print size of ArrayList.
        System.out.println("file2: " + list2.size());

        // Print each line.
        for (String line : list2) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        ArrayList<String> file1 = new ArrayList<String>(list1);
        ArrayList<String> file2 = new ArrayList<String>(list2);

        file1.removeAll(list2);
        file2.removeAll(list1);

        System.out.println(" ");    
        System.out.println("names in file1 that are not in file 2: " + file1);
        System.out.println("names in file2 that are not in file 1: " + file2);

        }//main

    }//class
```

Comment: Use `retainAll` instead of `removeAll`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Im sure was very dump question, I hope i ll get better soon. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through both arrays and do compare:

```
if(string1.equals(string2)){
  print(string1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the intersection between two collections using `retainAll`, e.g.

```
List<String> one = new ArrayList<>(); one.add("foo"); one.add("bar");
List<String> two = new ArrayList<>(); two.add("foo"); two.add("baz");

one.retainAll(two);
System.out.println(one);
```

will output:

```
[foo]
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/CT5c4q)